# Petri Net Verifier

Tags: testing, formal-verification, petri-net

Imagine I can specify a certain process as a Petri Net. Is there any good software, open source or not, that can verify my process against some conditions I declare (or code) in some language?

In case not, is there an open source software that does at least simulations?